# How to prove by induction with a set of equivalence sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

For example
Prove by induction that the operation of raising to the power m$\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ is well defined in $\mathbb{Z}_n$

$\forall$m$\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ $\forall$[x]$\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$/$_{{\sim}n}$

so that we have $[x^m]$=$[x]^m$

I am completely at lost here with this proof can someone please help.

Comment: Hint:$ (x-y)|(x^m-y^m)$

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, suppose $p = x^m \bmod n$.  Then show that $(x+n)^m \bmod n = p$.  With your basis case at $x \in \mathbb{Z}_n$, this should establish your proposition.